# How to Find whether Date and Time Format is wrong in n+ rows in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime, if-statement

In an exported excel different date format is available in Cloumn-A of an excel with 15000 rows. I Must one particular format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SS". I have used *=IF(A2="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SS","Yes","No")*
but it give "NO" to all the input.

Can anyone sort out the solution for me and where I did wrong

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi all One of my colleague help me out with a solution and its working great
*=IF(COUNTIF(A2,"????-??-?? ??:??:??.??"),"Yes","No")*
Guess someone could utilize from this answer

[image]